# NSURL may not respond warning +encryptedFileWithPath

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsurl, encryption

I am using the following code which is coming up with a warning. The code does display the correct image - but how can I get rid of the warning?

```
NSString *indexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"tunes"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL encryptedFileURLWithPath:indexPath];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

warning 'NSURL may not respond to +encryptedFileWithPath:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `NSURL` does not have a method called `encryptedFileWithPath:'. If you have copied your code from [here](http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/), you probably didn't read the article carefully enough:

> If you are familiar with NSURL and its class methods then you may have
>   spotted the unfamiliar encryptedFileURLWithPath: method. I have
>   extended NSURL using a category to add this method as a convenience.

Comment: Correct on both counts - great article. Forgot to  #import "NSURL+EncryptedFileURLProtocol.h".  Thanks again for your help.